# Assigning values to a static attribute from outside the file

Tags: python

The following `assign.py` should send the value correctly to `class1.py`.  However, the printing return 0.0. I made `dict` as a static so I can assign to it from outside file. Am I missing something?

**class1.py**

```
class Class1():
   dict = {}

   def set_dictionary(x,y,z):
       if (x, y) not in Class.dict:
          Class1.dict[(x, y)] = 0.0
       Class1.dict[(x,y)] = z
       print ("(%s --> %s) = %s" % (x,y,z))
```

**assign.py**

```
import class1 as cnt

cnt.Class1.set_dictionary('s1','s2', 100)
```

Comment: You should use a classmethod.

Comment: Your code doesn't work ("Class" is not defined) but when I fix that, it runs as expected. I cannot duplicate.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code? There is a conventional way to do object oriented programming in Python. The language lets you break those conventions. But that's usually a bad idea. In this case it's not at all clear what you expect this code to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, a [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod) is the way to go:

```
# class1.py
class Class1(object):
  dic = {}  # don't shadow built-ins

  @classmethod
  def set_dictionary(cls, x, y, z):
    cls.dic[(x,y)] = z
    print ("(%s --> %s) = %s" % (x, y, z))

# assign.py
import class1 as cnt
cnt.Class1.set_dictionary('s1','s2', 100)

>>> Class1.set_dictionary('s1','s2', 100)
(s1 --> s2) = 100
```

More on [the different kinds of methods in Python](https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods).